# ODataTFS to access Microsoft Test professional

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, tfs, odata

I have downloaded [Odata for TFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2013/01/07/odata-service-for-team-foundation-server-v2.aspx) and trying to use it. It was fairly easy to install and run and works a treat. It currently accesses Builds, Change sets, Branches, Links, Projects, Queries and so on...

I wanted to extend the functionality of the same to be able to access Microsoft Test professional. Access Test Suites, Test Cases and Tests.

Not sure where do I start from, any suggestions to extend the same would be really appreciated.

Under the ODataTFS.Model project from the solution, All the supported entities are defined. However, I do not have any reference to get the TestSuites in there.

[OData Source](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36230)

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? Test suites and test plans only became queryable work items in a fairly recent update.

Comment: @DanielMann The TFS I am targeting is 2012, although I wanted to support 2010 also. Meanwhile I know there is a better REST support without Odata for 2013 and now 2015.